# hasClass method and if statement execution

Tags: jquery, html

Please consider the following :
**HTML**

```
 <div id="left">
    <a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
    <a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('a.panel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
        animIn = function () {
            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        };

    if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: -$this.width()
            }, 500, animIn);
        });
    } else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        animIn();
    }
});

}); <br/>
```

As you see this code ( css not included here) creates sliding divs.
My problem is i see that `!$target.hasClass('active')` will always be FALSE,since `$target` does have a class active,which is added from the previous function using `addClass('active')`.
`$target.hasClass('active')` is TRUE while the preceding Not operator will make it always False.My question is,how would that if statement ever execute in that case? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is i see that `!$target.hasClass('active')` will always be FALSE,since $target does have a class active

No. `$target.hasClass('active')` would be false if `$target` does not have the active class. `!$target.hasClass('active')` is the opposite of that, so it would be `true` until the `animIn()` function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

`animIn`, called at some point when there is *no* "active" class, adds the "active" class. It is either called directly or in response to the animation finishing.

```
var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
    $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
    animIn = function () {
        $target.addClass('active').show().css({ // add class here
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    };

if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
    // not active, but has active sibling elements
    $other.each(function(index, self) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('active').animate({
            left: -$this.width()
        }, 500, animIn); // invoke animIn as animation callback,
                         // adding the class after the animation
    });
} else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
    // not active, no other element active
    animIn(); // invoke animIn immediately,
              // adding the class right now
}
// and if it already has the class, do nothing
```